# How to Create Wordpress Quickstart package?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a quickstart package with sample data, just like the Wordpress installation package. If this installation installs on any server it will look like a demo website. Could anyone tell me step by step how to create a quickstart package?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Theme Unit Test in the WordPress Codex. It's as easy as 1, 2, 3. Include the `theme-unit-test-data.xml` file into your "quickstart packages".

**Test Environment Setup**

1. Download test data:
   https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml
   (updated 01/06/14 16:36 UTC)
2. Import test data into your WordPress install. Do this by going to
   Tools -> Import.
3. Read [How To Join WPTRT](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/about/how-to-join-wptrt/), and follow all test-environment setup
   instructions

**Reference:**

> This step in Theme testing correlates to a WordPress export (WXR) file
>   that you can import into a WordPress installation to test your Theme.
>   To be clear, this is only one step in testing your Theme. See Theme
>   testing for a full guide.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test